# multipart form data POST with basic authentication fails

Tags: html, post, basic-authentication

I have the following form page to upload a file to a server. The server requires Authentication to complete and sends a 401 Unauthorized immediately in response to the POST request. However, the browsers IE, chrome, and Firefox all ignore the 401 and continue to post the data and eventually timeout. I would expect the browser to popup login window. What am I doing wrong!?

POST request

```
Http: Request, POST /cgi/upload 
  Command: POST
  URI: /cgi/upload
  ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
  Accept:  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
    Referer:  http://x.x.x.x/configuration/uploadImgfile.html?0
    Accept-Language:  en-US
    UserAgent:  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
  + ContentType:  multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de3c75d0a52
    Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
    Host:  16.93.62.215
    ContentLength:  7866893
    Connection:  Keep-Alive
    Cache-Control:  no-cache
    HeaderEnd: CRLF


server 401 reply

Http: Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Unauthorized, 
    URL: /cgi/upload , 
    Using Basic realm="XXXXX" Authentication
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
    StatusCode: 401, Unauthorized
    Reason: Unauthorized 
    Server:   eHTTP v2.0
    Connection:  close
  + WWWAuthenticate: Basic realm="XXXXX"
    HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Update Software</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function getlocation(){
      var url=window.location.href;
      var test=url.split("?");
      test=test[1];
      if(test == 0)
        document.sti.location.value="primary";
      else 
        document.sti.location.value="secondary";
     }
   </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getlocation();">
  <table border="0" align=center cellpadding="50">
    <tr>
    <td>
       <form name="sti" action="../cgi/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
       <input name="location" type="hidden"/>
       You can upload an Image.<p>
       File: <input name="imagefile" type="file"/><br/>
       <input name="reboot" type="checkbox" value="Reboot" checked />reboot
       </p>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
       <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="document.location='../configuration/configfilef.html';"/>
      </form>

   </td></tr></table>
 </body>
 </html>
```